# mysqli php query returns boolean when an integer is used as a condition

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a MySQL php query that will return a value when a string is used as a condition, but returns false when an integer is used.
this works,

```
    SELECT field FROM table WHERE name='john';
```

this doesn't

```
    SELECT field FROM table WHERE index='1';
```

here is an example of the row in question

```
    |index(int)|Name(varchar)|Field(varchar)|
    |   1      |    john     |    data      |
```

Is there an inherent problem with querying integers? anyone have any ideas?

Comment: When you check integer datatype value then never specify quotation

Comment: You are not querying an integer, you are querying a string. For an integer remove the quotes.

Comment: '1' is not an integer it's a string. 1 is a integer. Don't use '' when you want a number because index in your database is integer.

Comment: Dont use system reserved keyword

Comment: The reserved keyword in your case is `index`. You can solve this by putting backticks around it in the query. But better use a different name for the column, like id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the 'index' in your table name will be seen as a reserved keyword

In MySQL a lot of these **special characters or reserved words** exist. Every time you use one of those, **backticks** have to be used.

Backticks are to be used for table and column identifiers, but are only necessary when the identifier is a [MySQL reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), or when the identifier contains whitespace characters or characters beyond a limited set (see below) It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible, avoiding the quoting issue.

[According to MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html), you do not need to quote (backtick) identifiers using the following character set:

> ASCII: `[0-9,a-z,A-Z$_]` (basic Latin letters, digits 0-9, dollar, underscore)

You can use characters beyond that set as table or column identifiers, including whitespace for example, but then you *must* quote (backtick) them.

In your case using `index` (backticks!) instead of index should work

Comment: OR you could change the field name from `index` to something else - `id` is popular! :)